# Getting error "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file failed" in solaris

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am running a simulator which establishes SSL connections and sends HTTP requests.
But currently when I run the simulator I get below error:

> ERROR: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file failed ERROR: [SSL#906d06c]
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line ERROR:
>   [SSL#140ad009] error:140AD009:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib ERROR: Global SSL
>   initialization failed

Could anyone help me solve this issue?